# How do I create an std::thread that runs a member function of an abstract class?

Tags: multithreading, templates, c++11, polymorphism, virtual

I have something along the lines:

```
class Parent
{
private:
    std::thread t1;
protected:
    void ThreadFunction()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            SpecializedFunction();
        }
    }
    void CreateThread()
    {
        t1 = std::thread(&Parent::ThreadFunction, *this);
    }
    virtual void SpecializedFunction() = 0;
public:
    void Run()
    {
        CreateThread();
    }
}

class Child1 : public Parent
{
protected:
    void SpecializedFunction()
    {
        //code
    }
}

class Child2 : public Parent
{
protected:
    void SpecializedFunction()
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

But I have compile errors(It compiles if I comment the thread creation line). It says that it cannot specialize the decay method. I think the problem is either that Parent is abstract, either that the thread function is protected, but I'm not sure. Could you suggest a workaround/a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `*`, but be aware of lifetime issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    t1 = std::thread(&Parent::ThreadFunction, *this);
```

This will create a copy of `*this` and run the member function on the copy. In your case that fails, because you cannot create a copy of an abstract class, but making a copy is probably not what you wanted anyway.

To run the thread on the existing object pass a pointer:

```
    t1 = std::thread(&Parent::ThreadFunction, this);
```

or (since the resolution of [LWG 2219](https://wg21.link/lwg2219)) a reference:

```
    t1 = std::thread(&Parent::ThreadFunction, std::ref(*this));
```

As T.C. says in a comment above, you must ensure the object's lifetime does not end while the new thread is still running. You can do this by joining it in the destructor:

```
~Parent() { if (t1.joinable()) t1.join(); }
```

(If you don't join a `std::thread` before it is destroyed your program will terminate immediately!)

This is still not quite safe, because it only ensures the *base* class is not destroyed while the thread is still running, but the thread could be accessing the derived class, so you might need to ensure the thread is joined in the *derived* destructor.

Comment: The `std::ref` version depends on LWG 2219.

Comment: @T.C. yes I really should have remembered that since I reported it!

Comment: You can delegate the `join()` to the derived destructor instead of the base destructor because calling `join()` consecutive times throws an `invalid_argument` exception which is exactly what C++ will do as it traverses the class hierarchy calling destructors.

Comment: @Zenul_Abidin I'm not sure what you mean by "exactly what C++ will do as it traverses the class hierarchy". Why would it throw an `invalid_argument`? The base destructor could do `if (t1.joinable()) join();` so it only joins if the derived destructor didn't do it already.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I meant that in the base destructor, if you don't use the construct in your previous comment to check if the thread is already joined, then when you `join()` in the base destructor, it will throw `invalid_argument` (because it has already been joined in the derived destructor).

Comment: Can the `this` parameter be replaced with a pointer to the parent (abstract) class? If this was called from another class for example.

Comment: @SpencerSprowls yes of course.